# How to drop duplicates in a dataframe based on a second column value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

Suppose I have a `dataframe` called `state_df`:

```
DB_ID       InSFHA  
H198052997  0
H198052997  1
H198052997  1
H198052997  0
```

As you can see, I have duplicates in my DB_ID. I could simply drop them with the following:

```
state_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['DB_ID'])
```

But suppose I need to be selective in which one gets dropped. Suppose I want to drop the duplicates where the `InSFHA` column is 0. Using `state_df.duplicated(subset=['DB_ID']) will give me a series of all duplicates, but I am not sure how to apply that with the`InSFHA` column values to selectively drop the duplicates. Any suggestions?

Comment: `state_df[~state_df.duplicated(subset=['DB_ID']) | state_df['InSFHA'].ne(0)]`

Comment: This looks great. Question though: so it creates a new dataframe where the DB_ID is not a duplicate OR InSFHA = 0? Is that correct? Should it not be & instead of | ?